# darknet python api for webcam for detection in live video

Tags: python, yolo

i tried to modify the code in darknet.py to do detections in live video feed coming from the webcam. Just imported open cv library and did a bit of modifications in the main function. It was previously detecting single images i.e before importing opencv. But now i get this error. Can anyone please help ..

Error:

```
(python:7913): Gtk-ERROR **: GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Comment: Hello, can you provide the code that generate the error ?

Answer (score 0):

My main function looked like this :

if **name** == "**main**":

```
net = load_net("cfg/yolov3.cfg", "yolov3.weights", 0)
meta = load_meta("cfg/coco.data")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    cv2.imwrite('check.jpg',frame)
    r = detect(net, meta, "check.jpg")
    print r
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
```

Comment: This is a very slow way to use the python script for Darknet-Yolo as you are writing each frame to a file and then using it for detection. Consider my [repo](https://github.com/abhigarg/darknet-yolo-python) where you can pass the frame read from video source directly to the detect function.